# R dplyr - replace NA with 0 if

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe

```
dtf <- data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 4),
    amt = c(1, 4, NA, 123),
    xamt = c(1, 4, NA, 123),
    camt = c(1, 4, NA, 123),
    date = c("2020-01-01", NA, "2020-01-01", NA),
    pamt = c(1, 4, NA, 123)
)
```

I'd like to replace all NA values in case that colname is numeric, in my case amt, xamt, pamt and camt. I'm looking for dplyr way. Normally I would use

```
replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

But this not works because of date column.

Comment: In case one wants to use baseR: `rapply(dtf, classes = "numeric", f = function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0), how = "replace")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
dtf %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
#mutate_if for dplyr < 1.0.0
#dtf %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))
```

You can also use `replace_na` from `tidyr` :

```
dtf %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), tidyr::replace_na, 0))

#  id amt xamt camt       date pamt
#1  1   1    1    1 2020-01-01    1
#2  2   4    4    4       <NA>    4
#3  3   0    0    0 2020-01-01    0
#4  4 123  123  123       <NA>  123
```

As suggested by @Darren Tsai we can also use `coalesce`.

```
dtf %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), coalesce, 0))
```